# Is there any CSS property which keep .class:focus{--} property remain after clicking anywhere else than focused image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an animation on an image which is triggered when I focus/click on the image but the image loses its focus property/animation when clicking anywhere else.

```css
.paralx-dot-1:focus {
  animation-name:bright-dot;
  animation-duration:1.5s;
  height: 24.75px;
  width: 24.75px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes bright-dot {
  from { transform:scale(1,1); }
  to { transform:scale(2,2); }
}
```

This animation (https://ibb.co/wMmPCWW) happens when I click on image. When I click anywhere else after clicking on image/dot animation resets
(https://ibb.co/RjWbGzx)

Any way to prevent this to happen?
I want the focus to remain focused/animation if I click anywhere else.

Having no idea what to do! Any help is welcome.
Thanks

I tried this approach

```js
$('.paralx-dot-1').on('click', function () {
  $(this).transition({ scale: 1.5 });
});
```

It's working but it is applying transition on all the clicked images rather than the only clicked one

https://ibb.co/98TY7Jd

Comment: It's bad practice to force a user's focus on a particular element for a number of reasons. A better approach would be to add a class to the element on click, and have the class be the trigger to your css animation instead of the focus. That way the class persists even if you click elsewhere.

Comment: i'm learning and looking for alternate ways to do the same ! having no idea what approach i could go for ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a class to indicate it's now selected.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".paralx-dot-1").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".paralx-dot-1").removeClass('isSelected');
    $(this).addClass('isSelected');
  });
});
```

```css
.paralx-dot-1 {
  display:block;
  background-color:blue;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom:60px;
  transform:scale(1,1);
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.paralx-dot-1.isSelected {
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transform:scale(2,2);
  height: 24.75px;
  width: 24.75px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  color:#F00;
}



@keyframes example {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: yellow; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="paralx-dot-1"></div>
<div class="paralx-dot-1"></div>
<div class="paralx-dot-1"></div>
```